# html5 navigator.geolocation not work these few days

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, safari

I found that my website use navigator.geolocation is not working.
But I don't change any code.

I search many examples. I find that no any example is working now.

What is happend?

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Can you show us what have you done so far.

Comment: `navigator.geolocation` is not supported with http:// above chrome 50.0 - use https on your website instead if its possible.

Comment: @FelixHäberle  
Thank you for your reply, I know it is not supported after 50 of Chrome if you don't use https. But w3school's website use https and my website use https too. But they don't work too. And Safari dose not work too.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi My code like this example 

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

But I console out the navigator.geolocation, is always empty {}

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) `navigator.geolocation` is not going to be supported in **Chrome** with `http://` (**v50.0+**). Use `https://` instead if that's possible.

> **Note:** As of Chrome 50, the Geolocation API will only work on secure
>   contexts such as HTTPS. If your site is hosted on an non-secure origin
>   (such as HTTP) the requests to get the users location will no longer
>   function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I know it is not supported after 50 of Chrome if you don't use https.

But w3school's website use https and my website use https too. But they don't work too. And Safari dose not work too.

Comment: I had to accept some kind of security alert in the latest version of safari - maybe a local plugin/settings problem?

Comment: Because its working on your local machine doesnt mean that it works in Chrome 50+ with http. :)And do not forget to mark the accepted answer.

Comment: It works when running from a local web server but it doesn't work when running on web with http connection.